# React + Redux, How to render not after each dispatch, but after several?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to make multiple changes to the store, but not render till all changes are done. I wanted to do this with redux-thunk.

Here is my action creator:

```
function addProp(name, value) {
    return { type:'ADD_PROP', name, value }
}

function multiGeoChanges(...changes) {
    // my goal here is to make multiple changes to geo, and make sure that react doesnt update the render till the end
    return async function(dispatch, getState) {
        for (let change of changes) {
            dispatch(change);
            await promiseTimeout(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

I dispatch my async action creator like this:

```
store.dispatch(multiGeoChanges(addProp(1, "val1"), addProp(2, "val2"), addProp(3, "val3")));
```

However this is causing react to render after each `dispatch`. I am new to redux-thunk, I never used async middleware, but I thought it could help me here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are ways to achieve the goal:

**Classic way:**

usually:
Actions describe the ***fact that something happened***, but don't specify how the application's state changes in response. This is the job of reducers.
That also means that **actions are not setters**.

Thus, you could describe what has happened and accumulate changes, and dispatch **one** *action*
something like:

```
const multipleAddProp = (changedProps) =>({
   type:'MULTIPLE_ADD_PROP', changedProps
});
```

And then react on action in reducer:

```
const geo=(state,action)=>{
   ...
   switch (action.type){
   case 'MULTIPLE_ADD_PROP':
     // apply new props
   ...
   }
}
```

---

**Another way** When rerendering is critical :

then you can consider to limit components, which could be rerendered on state change.
For example you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to check whether component
should be rendered or not.
Also you could use *reselect*, in order to not rerender connected components 
after calculating  derived data...

---

**Non standard way:**
[redux-batched-action](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions)

It works something like transaction.

In this example, the subscribers would be notified once:

```
import { batchActions } from 'redux-batched-actions';

const multiGeoChanges=(...arrayOfActions)=> dispatch => {
    dispatch( batchActions(arrayOfActions) );
}
```

Comment: Aw darn. Thanks for this reply. I try not to get into too many libs. Just redux, react-router, and react. I just can't seem to find a use for redux-thunk. I feel as if it should help me, but I don't get it, I seem to be able to do things fine without it.

Comment: @Noitidart - thunk is really most useful for fetching remote data, especially if you need to make several calls from a single action.

Comment: Thanks @Snekse I use redux-saga now days :)

Comment: @Noitdart, `redux-thunk` is a trap best avoided. Their is almost always a better solution, I come across way to much anti-patten thunk code in peoples projects

Answer (score 14):

@Kokovin Vladislav's answer is correct.  To add some additional context:

Redux will notify all subscribers after *every* dispatch. To cut down on re-renders, either dispatch fewer times, or use one of several approaches for "batching" dispatches and notifications.  For more info, see the Redux FAQ on update events: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-update-events .

I also recently wrote a couple of blog posts that relate to this topic.  [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/) discusses the pros and cons of using thunks, and summarizes several ways to handle batching of dispatches.  [Practical Redux Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/) describes several key aspects to be aware of regarding Redux performance.

Finally, there's several other libraries that can help with batching up store change notifications.  See the [Store#Store Change Subscriptions](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#store-change-subscriptions) section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) for a list of relevant addons.  In particular, you might be interested in https://github.com/manaflair/redux-batch , which will allow you to dispatch an array of actions with only a single notification event.

Comment: Thank you @markerikson for such awesome links! I'm reading them now! My biggest need in redux is to batch and dispatch as one.

Comment: Your article on "why thunks" is awesome! I am having a hard time answering that for many months!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, as that post mentions, there's really four or five different ways you can accomplish "batching", depending on how you want to accomplish it. If you've got further questions, feel free to ping me on the Reactiflux chat channels ( http://www.reactiflux.com ).  I'm @acemarke , and usually on there evenings US EST.

Comment: Thank you so much for your friendly offer to chat with any questions!

Comment: Your blog posts are amazing! It is only the second time in my life that I subscribe to a blog. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 7):

In react-redux 7.0.1+ batching is now built-in. Release notes of 7.0.1:

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.1

> Batched Updates
>
> React has an unstable_batchedUpdates API that it uses to group
>   together multiple updates from the same event loop tick. The React
>   team encouraged us to use this, and we've updated our internal Redux
>   subscription handling to leverage this API. This should also help
>   improve performance, by cutting down on the number of distinct renders
>   caused by a Redux store update.

```
function myThunk() {

   return (dispatch, getState) => {

       // should only result in one combined re-render, not two

       batch(() => {

           dispatch(increment());

           dispatch(increment());

       })

   }

}
```

Comment: I understand why they use this internally, but not why they reexport this and give the above example. Actions should say what happened, not what you want to happen, that is why it is called React. In other words if you need to call more than one in the same place you are most likely missing the point. To me this just encourages anti-patten programming

Comment: @DavidBradshaw I can't recall where I copied that from, they might not allow that. Do you know if they do?

Comment: @DavidBradshaw What if you're using an action to trigger a loading indicator, one action to load data, and a third action to disable the loading indicator? This should cayse two renders, but two renders you actually want to happen. And it seems that with thunk, this is the only option you have to properly use a loading indicator because you cannot `await dispatch()` from the component itself.

Comment: @tshm001 in most use cases thunk is an anti-patten as well. For loading data checkout `redux-api-middleware`. It provides a much better solution for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

By design when the state, which is held by the store, changes the view should render.

You can avoid this by updating the state once.

If you are using promises you can use `Promise.all` to wait for all the promises to resolve and then dispatch a new action to the store with the calculated result. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Something like this:

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]).then(changes => { 
  dispatch(changes)
}, err => {
  // deal with error
});
```

Of course you'll need an action that will deal with many props, something like `addManyProps` this should update the state once, resulting in one render.

Comment: Thanks Sagi for this, this is interesting approach, +1.

Answer (score 0):

[**redux-batched-actions**](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions)
Batching action creator and associated higher order reducer for redux that enables batching subscriber notifications for an array of actions.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to this a bit late, but I think this is a much nicer solution, which enables you to add `meta.batch` to actions you would like to batch together into a single `react` update. As a bonus this approach works with asynchronous actions.

```
import raf from 'raf'
import { batchedSubscribe } from 'redux-batched-subscribe'

let notify = null
let rafId = null

const shouldBatch = action => action?.meta?.batch

export const batchedSubscribeEnhancer = batchedSubscribe(freshNotify => (notify = freshNotify))

export const batchedSubscribeMiddleware = () => next => action => {
  const resolved = next(action)

  if (notify && rafId === null && !shouldBatch(action)) {
    notify()
  } else if (!rafId) {
    rafId = raf(() => {
      rafId = null
      notify()
    })
  }

  return resolved
}
```

Then connect up to your store

```
mport { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { batchedSubscribeMiddleware, batchedSubscribeEnhancer } from './batching'

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  intialState,
  compose(
    batchedSubscribeEnhancer,
    applyMiddleware(batchedSubscribeMiddleware)
  )
)
```

Comment: In the latest redux, batching is now built-in.

Comment: @Noitidart, yes but their implementation only supports React, so doesn't help if you have your own subscribers on the Redux store and also only supports synchronous actions on the same event loop. In my case I have async actions generated via a subscription to a server message queue