# React Redux mapStateToProps not firing on update

Tags: react-redux

I have a connected component that maintains a display "state" along with a few other things that are needed for communication between a couple of components.  I have two connected components that are children of this over-arching component.  Depending on a flag that is within the "state" component one or the other child components will render.  It might be better to just show the code:

EditorState Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import Library from '../library/index';
import Editor from '../editor/index';

import {
  initialize,
  editorState
} from './actions';

class EditorState extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(initialize());
  }

  render() {
    const {state} = this.props;
    switch(state) {
      case editorState.Library:
        return <Library />
      case editorState.Editor:
        return <Editor />
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}

export default connect(state => {
  return state.EditorStateReducer;
})(EditorState);
```

EditorState Actions:

```
export const EDITOR_STATE_INITIALIZE = 'EDITOR_STATE_INITIALIZE';

export const editorState = {
  Library: 'library',
  Editor: 'editor'
}

export const initialize = ({
  type: EDITOR_STATE_INITIALIZE,
  state: editorState.Library
});
```

EditorState Reducer:

```
import {
  EDITOR_STATE_INITIALIZE
} from './actions';

const init = () => ({
  state: null
});

export default (state = init(), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case EDITOR_STATE_INITIALIZE:
      return {
        ...state, 
        state: action.state
      }
    default:
      return {...state}
  }
}
```

Library Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {Page} from '../../../components/page/index';

import LibraryItem from '../../../components/library-item/library-item';

import {
  initialize
} from './actions';

class Library extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(initialize());
  }

  render() {
    const {templates} = this.props;

    const editorTemplates = templates.map(template => 
      <LibraryItem template={template} />
    );

    return (
      <Page>
        <div className="card-flex library-table">
          {editorTemplates}
        </div>
      </Page>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(state => {
  return state.LibraryReducer;
})(Library);
```

Library Actions:

```
import {
  client,
  serviceUrl
} from '../../../common/client';

export const LIBRARY_INITIALIZE = 'LIBRARY_INITIALIZE';

export const initialize = () => dispatch => {
  client.get(`${serviceUrl}/templates`).then(resp => {
    dispatch({
      type: LIBRARY_INITIALIZE,
      templates: resp.templates
    });
  });
}
```

Library Reducer:

```
import {
  LIBRARY_INITIALIZE
} from './actions';

const init = () => ({
  templates: []
});

export default (state = init(), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LIBRARY_INITIALIZE:
      return {
        ...state,
        templates: action.templates
      }
    default:
      return {...state}
  }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that the mapStateToProps in the Library Component is not being called upon the dispatch of LIBRARY_INITIALIZE.  I have breakpoints in both mapStateToProps in the EditorState and Library, and a breakpoint in the LIBRARY_INITIALIZE switch in the Library reducer.  Debugging page load goes like this:

EditorState mapStateToProps - state.EditorStateReducer.state is null

EditorState mapStateToProps - state.EditorStateReducer.state == editorState.Library

Library mapStateToProps - state.LibraryReducer.templates == []

Library Reducer Initialize - action.templates == [{template1}, {template2}, etc]

EditorState mapStateToProps - **state.LibraryReducer.templates** == [{template1}, {template2}, etc]

Then nothing.  I would expect the Library mapStateToProps to fire as well after this so that the Library can re-render with the templates.  However, this is not happening.  Why is this not happening?  I am ready to pull my hair out over this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot be 100% sure that the updated state is rendered right after the dispatch call. mapStatetoProps is called when the component is about to re-render, which depends on whether React batches the updates or not. By default, React batches updates from event handlers.

You can refer https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/291

Comment: If that is the case then why would the EditorState mapStateToProps be fired after the dispatch and have the data in the correct reducer that I need?  mapStateToProps is called for every subscriber upon a dispatch so that the props can be updated so React can determine whether to re-render or not.  It's not the other way around.

I appreciate you trying to help, but this is not correct.  If it was, Redux would not work properly with React.

You can refer to the response markerikson gave in this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646353

Comment: So I did some more experimentation upon seeing who was answering the question in your link.  I added a libraryInitialize variable to the LibraryReducer and then in the componentWillReceive props on EditorState I dispatched a throw away action if the new libraryInitialize did not equal the old.  Sure enough, the mapStateToProps in the Library fires with the correct templates values.  I am marking this as the accepted answer because it was exactly it.  However, this seems like a severe limitation of Redux not to handle hierarchical connected components very well.

Comment: Yes that's true, when I had the same issue. What I had found was firing dependent actions is kind of anti pattern. You should club your dependent actions and put as much business logic in reducers as possible, than firing one and waiting for props to flow down to fire the dependent action. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  However, the way that I was trying to do this was not using dependent actions.  In fact, I have to introduce dependent actions just to get it to work right now.  What I was trying to do was to introduce a top-level container component above my two page level container components.  However, it is what it is and I'm going to have to rethink my approach because of this limitation of react-redux.  Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Wow, this was super helpful! I was already getting crazy as I could not understand why mapStateToProps does not update my props even though the store has been correctly updated clearly paying attention to not mutating the existing state by returning a copy in the reducer. But most answers to be found for this topic revolve around immutability issues not around this exact issue here. The information that mapStateToProps is not necessarily being called directly after each single dispatch was new to me but super helpful! Thanks a lot!