# How can I tell Redux not to update React state yet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently dealing with a very large table of data. Some actions the user can take are quite complex - complex enough that I might end up `dispatch`ing a hundred actual actions to Redux, many of which will depend on the state being updated by previous actions, and causing a hundred state changes... which will result in the page seeming to lock up as numerous things in a very large table are rendered a hundred times, even though none of these updates will be individually meaningful to the user (or actively confusing)

Is there a way to delay Redux/React from seeing these changes - to say "okay, don't bother pestering React about this stuff, don't recalculate any props, don't do *anything* but throw this stuff through the reducers until it's done and I tell you it's done, and then return to normal behaviour" ?

I know I could set some React state property and then have a shouldUpdateComponent in each of my many components, but I was hoping there was a solution that involved less duplicate code scattered across dozens of files and perhaps even a bit more efficiency of avoiding calling the same exact function dozens of times per update.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646353/react-redux-how-to-render-not-after-each-dispatch-but-after-several?

Comment: Similar question, but without the important "actions dispatched are dependent on the current state" bit - none of the selected answer's responses are useful in that situation. markerikson posted a lot of links though, and maybe one of those can help, so thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Dan Abramov himself wrote on twitter an example of how to do this using batched actions and a higher order reducer.

https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/656074974533459968?lang=en

The gist of the idea is to wrap the actions you want to batch in another action, and define a higher order reducer (a reducer that returns another reducer, eg. redux-undo) that will apply all these actions when it handles the batched action update.

Comment: Does this work when the actions sent are dependent on the results of prior actions? Maybe that's included in the "define a higher order reducer" part... does that mean you're essentially returning a... i dunno, a "mirror" of the state and updating/reading from that instead of the real store?

Comment: Also, the link in his tweet doesn't actually work, so I can't actually see the example. Do you know where it actually is?